# Can Detox be used to run tests on a physical android device?

Tags: android, jestjs, cicd, detox

I am new to Detox. For my project I need to choose between Appium and Detox. I've used Appium before and find it to be quite straight-forward in terms of installation and CI/CD integration. However Detox is completely the opposite. From my initial attempts experimenting with it I have already run into issues:

- Installation on windows is not straight-forward. I followed the [procedure explained here](https://wix.github.io/Detox/docs/19.x/introduction/getting-started).  Managed to get something set-up. Now I need to figure out how to write the first test. That brought me to my next question regarding Detox.
- How to locate an app that's already installed on a physical android device and launch it? In Appium it is as straight-forward as navigating through the different pages and locating the app using it's name.
- From what I've read about Detox, it seems that the test app needs to be built alongside the app that needs to be tested i.e. the tests are to be integrated within the app project. Can the test project be separate from the project that builds the app? Since this will be the case if one were to use a Windows environment for the tests.